# Install Python modules on new Python version

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I've used easy_install to get one or two modules, then I used pip to install the Twitter module.

However the newer version of Python I downloaded can't see these modules, only the built in OSX version can.

Also, I am now unable to download NLTK which I need for some examples I'm working through on a really good book called "Mining the Social Web".

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to install the modules for the new python as well.

Answer (score 1):

Install the packages with the binary from your version of python.
So for example if your version is in /usr/local/bin then installing would be either:

- /usr/local/bin/python setup.py ...
- /usr/local/bin/easy_install  ...
- /usr/local/bin/pip install ...

Comment: Mihai, what's the 1st line for? I don't have a setup.py script in my usr/local/bin

Comment: The first line is for packages you download and build yourself. setup.py is part of the downloaded package. I just enumerated the standard ways a python package can be installed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the modules you downloaded are compatible with the version of Python you are trying to run.  I can't really figure out what module / Python versions you are talking about, but if it's compatible, all you would need to do is add the module path to the PYTHONPATH.  You can do this either in your environment variable or within you python script.

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH):

> PYTHONPATH¶
>
> Augment the default search path for module files. The format is the same as the shell’s PATH: one or more directory pathnames
>   separated by os.pathsep (e.g. colons on Unix or semicolons on
>   Windows). Non-existent directories are silently ignored.
>
> In addition to normal directories, individual PYTHONPATH entries may refer to zipfiles containing pure Python modules (in either source
>   or compiled form). Extension modules cannot be imported from zipfiles.
>
> The default search path is installation dependent, but generally begins with prefix/lib/pythonversion (see PYTHONHOME above). It is
>   always appended to PYTHONPATH.
>
> An additional directory will be inserted in the search path in front of PYTHONPATH as described above under Interface options. The
>   search path can be manipulated from within a Python program as the
>   variable sys.path.

Note that the last sentence refers to the second method I mentioned, adding search a path inside your Python file.

Comment: I have version 2.7.1 which is the default version that came with OSX Lion. However I also downloaded a newer version from python.org (3.2.2) and I'd like to use that with the modules I download.

Comment: There have been a lot of things that were deprecated and removed between 2.7.1 and 3.2.2.  Provided that the modules you downloaded are 3.2.2 compatible, you should be able to add them to your PYTHONPATH either through the environment variable or programmatically within the script itself.

Comment: See this (http://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/path.html) for the code snippet to add to your path from within a python program.